# Which is first in order @PostConstruct or onload?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

i was wondering what happens first in the order the @postconstruct method in my backing bean or the onload JS in the view side ?

Comment: What happens if you try it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@PostConstruct` is a server side method. `onload` function is a client side function. No matter what, `@PostConstruct` will always be executed before the response is rendered and hence, before `onload`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `@PostConstruct` will go off first. To be more precise, after the bean is initiated, the `@PostConstruct` function would fire. When the response of the server arrives at your browser, `onload` function will fire when the view is being rendered.